# Hook variable for horizontal scrolling

Tags: hooks, scrolling

There is the hook variable `window-scroll-functions` for functions to be called before redisplay after vertical scrolling.

Is there a similar variable for horizontal scrolling?

Comment: I access this information from within C when working on my own feature requests, but I don't think there is a hook available to the end user.  You may wish to look at things such as `w->hscroll` (greater than zero when scrolling) and `w->suspend_auto_hscroll` and the value of `auto-hscroll-mode`.  Keep in mind that there is also a feature of horizontal scrolling of the current line in recent versions of Emacs

Comment: I don't find anything for this. And horizontal scrolling (e.g. `C-<`) is defined in C. So I'm guessing there is nothing for this. You might want to file an enhancement request (`M-x report-emacs-bug`).